# How $2$ is come here?

Tags: real-analysis

find the  value $\prod_{n=2}^{\infty} \left( 1- \frac{1}{n^2}\right)$

I got the  answer  here [image]

My doubt is that  How  $2$  is  come here ?

## My attempt :

$\prod_{=2}^{n} 
\frac {k-1}{k} \prod_{k=2}^{n} \frac{k+1}{k}  = \frac{n+1}{n}$

I don't know  how  $2$ come  here

Comment: Try the product for small values of $n$. You will see that you have a remaining $2$ as well as a remaining $n$ on the bottom after you cancel everything.

Comment: The part you're asking about specifically is probably best explained in the answer from астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг (i.e., "Aston Villa Olof Mellberg").  The answer explaining the telescoping get at the $\frac12$ part more directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first :
$$
\prod_{k=2}^n \frac{k-1}{k} = \frac {\color{blue}1}2 \frac 23 .. \frac {n-1}{\color{green}n} = \frac 1n 
$$

The second :
$$
\prod_{k=2}^n \frac{k+1}{k} =\boxed{\frac{3}{\color{green} 2}} \frac 43 \frac 54 ... \frac{\color{blue}{n+1}}{n} = \frac{n+1}{2}
$$

So the $2$ comes from the first term of the second product which does not cancel out. Had the product been from $k=\color{orange}{1}$ to $n$, that would have cancelled the $2$.

Answer (score 1):

It is a telescoping product, $$\prod_{n=2}^{m \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1- \frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
$$ = \prod\dfrac{(k-1)(k+1)}{k^2} $$
$$= \prod_2^m(k-1) \prod_2^m(k+1) /\prod(k^2)$$
$$=\prod_1^{m-1} k \prod_3^{m+1}k/\prod_2^m(k^2)=\dfrac{(m+1)}{2(m)} \rightarrow 1/2 $$

Answer (score 1):

Note that the product telescopes

$$\prod_{k=2}^n=\frac{(k-1)(k+1)}{k^2}=\frac12\cdot \color{red}{\frac32 \cdot \frac23\cdot \frac43 \cdot \frac 34 \cdot \frac54\cdot \ldots \cdot \frac {n-1}n}\cdot \frac {n+1}n$$

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to see it if you just expand the products you have. For example the first product in your attempt is

\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
\prod_2^n \frac{k - 1}{k} &= \frac{2 - 1}{2} \cdot \frac{3 - 1}{3} \cdot \frac{4 - 1}{4} \dotsb \frac{n - 1}{n} \\
&= \frac{1}{\cancel{2}} \cdot \frac{\cancel{2}}{\cancel{3}} \cdot \frac{\cancel{3}}{\cancel{4}} \dotsb \frac{\cancel{n - 1}}{n} \\
&= \frac{1}{n}.
\end{align}

Now you can try the second product.